# Jquery $.validator.addMethod not getting called

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I have referred the documents & stack overflow for this problem where i found some solutions & even i tried manipulating accordingly but those dint work for me. So finally i have posted this here.

When i click submit its directly going to **submitHandler** & not validating with respective to the defined custom method **select_not_default** & i tried putting alert in this custom method but it doesn't call that **means something wrong with custom method or jquery including order or jquery version i am using**.

Please help me to find where i am doing wrong. so confused from past two days.

This is the order i have included the jquery & validation plugins:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.1.8/cruise_booking/application/assets/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

Below is the HTML form:

```
<form action="http://192.168.1.8/cruise_booking/booking/availability" method="post" id="availability_form">
<!-- SIDEBAR AVAILBBILITY -->
<div class="reservation-sidebar_availability bg-gray">

    <!-- HEADING -->
    <h2 class="reservation-heading">YOUR RESERVATION</h2>
    <!-- END / HEADING -->
<select class="awe-select" name="source" id="source">
    <option value="0">Source</option>
    <option value="1">Goa</option>
    <option value="3">Mumbai</option>
</select>
<select class="awe-select" name="destination" id="destination">
    <option value="0">Destination</option>
    <option value="2">Goa</option>
    <option value="4">Mumbai</option>
</select>
<select class="awe-select" name="month" id="month">
    <option value="0">Month</option>
    <option value="Oct/2017">Oct/2017</option>
    <option value="Nov/2017">Nov/2017</option>
</select>
<dddc id="date_dd_container">
<select class="awe-select" name="date" id="date">
    <option value="0">Dates</option>
    <option value="1">2017-10-12 09:30:00</option>
</select>
</dddc>
<select class="awe-select" name="adults" id="adults">
    <option value="0">Adults</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="awe-select" name="children" id="children">
    <option value="0">Children</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="awe-select" name="infants" id="infants">
    <option value="0">Infants</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
    <div class="vailability-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="search_btn" class="awe-btn awe-btn-13" value="Search">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END / SIDEBAR AVAILBBILITY -->
</form>
```

Below is the code to validate the form.

```
$.validator.addMethod("select_not_default", function(value, element) {
            var d = parseInt(value);
            alert(d);
            if(d == 0)
            {
                return false;           
            }
            else
                return true;
            }); 

            $("#availability_form").validate({
            rules: {
                source: {
                    required: true,
                    select_not_default: true
                },
                destination: {
                    required: true,
                    select_not_default: true
                },
                month: {
                    required: true,
                    select_not_default: true
                },
                date: {
                    required: true,
                    select_not_default: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                source: {
                    required: "This field is required",
                    select_not_default: "Choose any other value than default one."
                },
                destination: {
                    required: "This field is required",
                    select_not_default: "Choose any other value than default one."
                },
                month: {
                    required: "This field is required",
                    select_not_default: "Choose any other value than default one."
                },
                date: {
                    required: "This field is required",
                    select_not_default: "Choose any other value than default one."
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                    alert("hi");
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is wait until the [document is ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) with:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("select_not_default", function(value, element) {
      var d = parseInt(value);
      if(d == 0)
      {
          return false;
      }
      else
          return true;
  });

  $("#availability_form").validate({
      rules: {
          source: {
              required: true,
              select_not_default: true
          },
          destination: {
              required: true,
              select_not_default: true
          },
          month: {
              required: true,
              select_not_default: true
          },
          date: {
              required: true,
              select_not_default: true
          }
      },
      messages: {
          source: {
              required: "This field is required",
              select_not_default: "Choose any other value than default one."
          },
          destination: {
              required: "This field is required",
              select_not_default: "Choose any other value than default one."
          },
          month: {
              required: "This field is required",
              select_not_default: "Choose any other value than default one."
          },
          date: {
              required: "This field is required",
              select_not_default: "Choose any other value than default one."
          }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
          console.log("hi");
          form.submit();
      }
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form action="http://192.168.1.8/cruise_booking/booking/availability" method="post" id="availability_form">
<!-- SIDEBAR AVAILBBILITY -->
<div class="reservation-sidebar_availability bg-gray">

    <!-- HEADING -->
    <h2 class="reservation-heading">YOUR RESERVATION</h2>
    <!-- END / HEADING -->
<select class="awe-select" name="source" id="source">
    <option value="0">Source</option>
    <option value="1">Goa</option>
    <option value="3">Mumbai</option>
</select>
<select class="awe-select" name="destination" id="destination">
    <option value="0">Destination</option>
    <option value="2">Goa</option>
    <option value="4">Mumbai</option>
</select>
<select class="awe-select" name="month" id="month">
    <option value="0">Month</option>
    <option value="Oct/2017">Oct/2017</option>
    <option value="Nov/2017">Nov/2017</option>
</select>
<dddc id="date_dd_container">
<select class="awe-select" name="date" id="date">
    <option value="0">Dates</option>
    <option value="1">2017-10-12 09:30:00</option>
</select>
</dddc>
<select class="awe-select" name="adults" id="adults">
    <option value="0">Adults</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="awe-select" name="children" id="children">
    <option value="0">Children</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="awe-select" name="infants" id="infants">
    <option value="0">Infants</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
    <div class="vailability-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="search_btn" class="awe-btn awe-btn-13" value="Search">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END / SIDEBAR AVAILBBILITY -->
</form>
```